# C# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString - Passing value like http://http://helloworld returns true. Is this by design or a bug?

Tags: c#, uri

Sorry if this is already answered (I couldn't find it when I searched), if you pass an invalid URL value like "http://http://helloworld" should return false for Uri.IsWellFormedUriString in c#.

However, it is returning true (at least with .Net Framework 4.5). I would like to know the logic behind treating this as a well formed Uri string. 
Or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RFC 3986 never said the path cannot contain ://

Comment: Please mark the correct answer and upvote the helpful posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

Beginning in .NET 4.5, strings are always considered well-formed in accordance with RFC 3986 and RFC 3987, whether or not IRI or IDN are enabled.

`RFC 3986` and `3987` never said the path cannot contain

```
://
```

In fact if you scroll down to the remark section of the doc where it describes the errors

> The string is an absolute URI that is missing a slash before the path.
>
> ```
> file://c:/directory/filename
> ```

which implies that

```
file:///c:/directory/filename
```

is considered a valid Uri under RFC 3986 and 3987. It does look like an invalid Uri if you replaced file with http but still its valid under the standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't validate the format of the uri, as the documentation mentions it concerns about character escaping:

> Indicates whether the string is well-formed by attempting to construct a URI with the string and **ensures that the string does not require further escaping**.

If you want to validate the format you can use [`Uri.TryCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: It DOES validate the format. In versions of .NET before version 4.5, by default the string is considered well-formed in accordance with RFC 2396 and RFC 2732. Beginning in .NET 4.5, strings are always considered well-formed in accordance with RFC 3986 and RFC 3987, whether or not IRI or IDN are enabled.

Comment: @Steve I have read that, but I don't think this is validating format. valid format and well formed are different things imo. if u say this is validating format then why I can not create a uri like this `http://http://helloworld` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx

Like the name `IsWellFormedUriString()` suggests, it just checks for the well-formed URI `string` and having **HTTP 2 times** in a string does not cause any discrepancy.